# Create multiline fraction

Tags: equations, amsmath, fractions

How to create an equation like in the image below. I tried to use `\cfraq` and `\hline` but with no success. I am asking for the layout only, not the formulae.

[image]

Comment: What should be the rule governing the separator lines in the left column?

Comment: @egreg I am afraid I do no understand the question, could you paraphrase ? They should be as long as the equation below them.

Comment: That was the question. ;-)

Comment: @egreg I can easily recreate this with align I just do not know how to add these lines.

Comment: Why don't you post the code that you have to this point, for us to use a starting point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,collcell}

\newenvironment{productions}
 {\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{
    >{\collectcell\firstcolumn}c<{\endcollectcell}
    >{\displaystyle}l
  }
 }
 {\end{array}
  \global\firstcelltrue
  \end{equation*}}

\newif\iffirstcell
\firstcelltrue

\newcommand{\firstcolumn}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
  \iffirstcell
    \global\firstcellfalse
  \else
    \addlinespace[2ex]\midrule\addlinespace[2ex]
  \fi
  $\displaystyle#1$
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{productions}
b \xrightarrow{b} \surd &
  (\frac{}{v\xrightarrow{v}\surd},
   \quad v:=b) \\    
a+b \xrightarrow{b} \surd &
  (\frac{y\xrightarrow{v}\surd}{x+y\xrightarrow{v}\surd},
   \quad v:=b, x:=a, y:=b) \\
(a+b)\cdot c \xrightarrow{b} c &
  (\frac{x\rightarrow{v}\surd}{x\cdot y\xrightarrow{v}y},
   \quad v:=b, x:=a+b, y:=c) \\    
((a+b)\cdot c)\cdot d \xrightarrow{b} c\cdot d &
  (\frac{x\rightarrow{v}x'}{x\cdot y\xrightarrow{v}x'\cdot y},
   \quad \!
   \begin{aligned}[t]
   & v:=b, x:=(a+b)\cdot c, \\
   & x':=c, y:=d) \\
   \end{aligned}
\end{productions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW, you are a tex machine :)

Comment: @tdi The Joy of TeX!